# how change image domain using jquery while page loading

Tags: html, jquery

I am extracting the table from the url http://rid3201.org/site/club_members2.php?id=MTk3Ng== by using ajax jquery and append into a div. But i cant access the images from that table because of different domain. How can i solve this problem. content are extracted by using the following code

```
        $.ajax(
        {
        url: '/Member/DownloadUrlData',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (request) {

        },
        success: function (data) {
           // $('#rData').load('data #container');

            var html = $.parseHTML(data);
            var table = $(html).find('#container>table:first');

           $("#rData").append(table);

       },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    },
        complete: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
       }
   });
```

Comment: you able to fetch image ? if yes in what is the url format ? and also tell in which url format you want image.

Comment: i cant fetch the url. i want the full path like http://rid3201.org/rotary-db1/images/zcabycpaulputhencruz11050.jpg insted of ../rotary-db1/images/zcabycpaulputhencruz11050.jpg

Comment: are you getting this path correctly ../rotary-db1/images/zcabycpaulputhencruz11050.jpg  ?

Comment: yes i got the path like ../rotary-db1/images/zcabycpaulputhencruz11050.jpg

Comment: before appending the table data to a div you can replace the image path.

Comment: var last=$(table).$("#table > img").attr("src", "http://rid3201.org/" + $("#table>img").attr("src")); i use this. but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var table = $(html).find('#container>table:first');
table.find('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://rid3201.org/" + $(this).attr("src").replace('..', ''));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table img').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "http://rid3201.org/" + $(this).attr("src").replace('..', ''));
    });
});
```

Working Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/KGGaG/2/

Comment: alert out the output of this code `$("#table>img").attr("src")` and reply me the code
and provide a link to project of it's running online

Comment: i take the images from http://rid3201.org/site/club_members2.php?id=MTk3Ng== i want take all the images. and table contains all image. i think that's why the problem. how can i put a loop in this

Comment: i put an alert in loop. but its not entered in loop

Comment: currently the code is var html = $.parseHTML(data);
                var table = $(html).find('#container>table:first');
                $('table img').each(function () {
                    alert("loop");
                    $(this).attr("src", "http://rid3201.org/" + $(this).attr("src").replace('..', ''));

                });
                
                $("#rData").append(table);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34033/discussion-between-user2598044-and-tushar-gupta)

Comment: good but you neither upvoted me nor marked my answer as answer :/